# Adding spaces between JavaScript exports and braces causes compilation error (Angular 14)

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following a course about NgRx, and I'm using Angular 14 with Node 16.

I am using the code reformatting features of Webstorm.

```js
import * as AuthActions from "./auth.actions";

export {AuthActions};
```

into this:

```js
import * as AuthActions from './auth.actions';

export { AuthActions };
```

`AuthActions` is imported in another file, and when I run the application with reformatted code I get this error:

> Error: export 'AuthActions' (imported as 'AuthActions') was not found in '../action-types' (module has no exports)

I've always used spaces inside braces, and this is the first time I get this error. Does anyone know which could be the cause?

If it could help, the code can be found on https://github.com/angular-university/ngrx-course.
I started building my application from branch **1-start**, whose latest commit is currently **Upgrade to NgRx 14**, and the complete code is on branch **master**.
My application is still incomplete but the files that are giving this problem (`src/app/auth/action-types.ts` and `src/app/auth/reducers/index.ts`) are identical to branch `master` except for code formatting.

Comment: Something else is wrong here. The two code variants are both valid and exactly equivalent.

Comment: Something weird is happening here. I have a similar file, with spaces inside braces, which was compiling fine. I kept writing code and I made many commits. Now I get the same compilation error for that new file, I checked out the commit on which that file was introduced, and I am still getting that error. The code used to work, the code I wrote after that used to work, now it does not work anymore. I think there is something wrong with Node.js.